# Chassis fans and power LEDs still work in Hibernate

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

I have ASRock Z68 Extreme3 Gen3 motherboard recently updated to 2.20 BIOS version. OS is Windows 7 x64. The problem is after that update full hibernation (by that i mean full system power off) stopped working although everything was fine before. Now when I press hibernate, sleep in initiated as usual, monitor goes to sleep, HDD and CPU fan stop spinning, but chassis fans (i have Gigabyte Aurora 3D 570 case with two rear and one front fans) still remain working. Also power leds are lit as if computer is turned on.  Tried changing different UEFI settings related to sleep mode, and none of them change above described behaviour. I have "Deep Sleep" (Advanced-South Bridge Configuration) set to "Enabled in S4-S5", "Suspend to RAM" (Advanced-ACPI Configuration) set to "Auto", all fans settings in "H/W Monitor" set to "Auto".
*edit*
There's definitely a problem with power management somewhere - Shutdown/Power Off command has same effect - everything is shutting down, but fans are spinning, leds lit and i can "wake" PC  by usb mouse (?). 
*edit2*
Tried another PSU, no changes. After i switched back mine, everything was fine again as usual (power off shuts down, hibernate suspends with all leds and fans turn off). Almost wanted to close the topic, but... After reboot Dr.Debug showed error 55 (ram not installed), and then system turned to be dead. Had to reset CMOS and remove power plugs, wait some time, and only then system turns on.

Comment: Have you tried Power Option (advances power settings) and checked your sleep settings?

Comment: Tried both hibernate enabled and disabled - no effect.

Comment: Are the chassis fans plugged into the motherboard or the case?

Comment: Three chassis fans have one connector plugged into mb CHA_FAN2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by putting in v1 bios chip sent by ASRock technical support.

Answer (score 0):

Do they remain spinning as long as the computer is plugged in, or just for a few minutes?  Some systems will continue to run the fans for a few minutes after shutdown to ensure proper cooling of the system.  I have an AsRock Z68 board as well (not the same one as you) and some of my fans run for an extra 1-2 minutes after shutdown.  (I couldn't tell you which ones, since I almost never shut the thing off...)

Comment: First option. The same for Power LEDs.